# Why my application icons wiggle when I press ALT key in Launchpad?

Tags: keyboard, launchpad

I tried Launchpad first time today and went through the common modifier keys & their combinations to see if some hidden options appear.

When I pressed <kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd> all the apps started wiggling. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiggle is the edit mode. (so you can delete or uninstall the apps that came from the app store)

Holding alt is the quickest way to enter edit mode.

Comment: What is "edit mode" then? I can reorder the apps even while nothing wiggles. Is it something else?

Comment: I'll clarify the answer - it makes it so you can delete apps from the app store - i was wrong to say reorder. iOS has trained me to think you can only reorder icons in edit mode - but that's not so on the Mac Launchpad. Confusingly (to me), you can even launch an app in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you click and hold them they also start wiggling. It lets you drag them around, to re-arrange them, and also delete apps from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Holding also wiggles—true. But I can drag them and rearrange them even *when they're not wiggling;* hence I presume that wiggling doesn't mean just draggability.

Answer (score 0):

When they are wiggling you can rearrange them AND delete/remove apps that you yourself have downloaded. System apps (like iOS) cannot be deleted.

Comment: System apps and **[non-Appstore apps](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17863/how-do-you-delete-apps-from-lions-launchpad)**, it seems. Would the Appstore apps wiggle too if I had them or would they stand still?