# How to remove icons showing question marks of deleted apps from Launchpad?

Tags: macos, icon, launchpad

I updated GIMP from MacUpdates since then I got two Gimp icons in Launchpad. I also deleted the Gimp.app from finder but now i get this question mark on the gimp icon in Launchpad. How to completely remove both of these icons?

[image]

What is the cleanup step, here?

Comment: This image is a [nice addition to other ways to remove icons from LaunchPad](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17863/how-do-you-delete-apps-from-lions-launchpad).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Worked] In Yosemite open Launchpad, hold down control key and click on icon you wish to remove. A question mark should appear over the icon. Just drag and drop to Trash.

Comment: This also works on Big Sur

Comment: This also works on Monterey.

Comment: In macOS 13 Ventura, you have to hold the Option key instead. They will wiggle and you can click the X. If I hold Control or Command and click, it just tries to launch the app.

Answer (score 5):

In my occasion all the shortcuts had the question marks on it, so I didn't have a use of CTRL+Click (and it didn't work). However as @user310633 mentioned, the Kill command as below worked.

[image: A screenshot of the icons with question marks in my situation]

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true && killall Dock
```

PS: Sorry I had too create a new comment to add my experience as my reputation score on this forum doesn't let me answer on previous comments.

Comment: Caution: This will not only remove the question marks but also rebuild the whole launchpad and the original structure will not remain.

Answer (score 2):

Worked exactly as indicated above. Hold control and click the offending icon and it will appear with a ? over it, drag it to the trash bin and it's gone.  Works Even with problem icons that do not show up in finder, had ostensibly been deleted by appcleaner and did not show an X when jiggling mode entered.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! 
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Let's leave this. It's clearly looking to add context to the brief accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true && killall Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

If the unwanted icons stuck in Mac Launchpad come from an app installed and uninstalled on a "Windows" virtual machine, one way to remove them is to click Finder on the Mac screen, and then select Macintosh HD > Applications folder, and then trash the files with those unwanted icons.

Comment: Additional info from the Parallels KB: http://kb.parallels.com/en/112798

Answer (score 0):

on mac 11 When i long click on a app (like on the iPhone) it appear an mini x on the app when i clicked the app it ask me if i want to delete the app