# How to remove duplicate icons from Launchpad?

Tags: macos, xcode, launchpad

I have two identical Xcode icons in the Launchpad. I guess the second icon appeared after installing Xcode beta.

So here my steps for reproducing this issue:

1. Install Xcode 7.
2. Install Xcode 8.
3. Install Xcode 7 again.

I tried [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175990/196476) but it didn't help me. I have OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

How do I remove the duplicate icon?

[image: two xCode icons]

Comment: Have you held the icon still they start shaking, and then pressing the little `x`?

Answer (score 2):

What @ruddfawcett said has worked for me. Click and hold an application icon and many applications on that screen will start to shake and they will have a small x appear on the top left of the shaking icons. The apps with the x can be removed by clicking on the x. Don't forget to empty trash once you are positive you have discarded the right app.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me. Try to move the Xcode App to Trash and put it back.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519772/two-xcode-app-icons-in-launchpad-after-4-5-install